# Changing the dimension value as measure

Tags: mdx, mdxstudio

i want to use the dimension value as calculated measure

```
case when [time].[month].current member is 
        [time].[month].&[januaray] then 'januaray'

        when [time].[month].&[feb] then 'feburary'
else 'None' end
```

i want to display for these 12 months values as measures

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use either the property `MemberValue`, `Member_Value`, or `MemberCaption`

So just the following:

```
[time].[month].currentMember.membervalue
```

or

```
[time].[month].currentMember.member_value
```

or

```
[time].[month].currentMember.member_Caption
```

You should **not** need to do this in `mdx`:

```
case when [time].[month].current member is 
        [time].[month].&[januaray] then 'januaray'

        when [time].[month].&[feb] then 'feburary'
else 'None' end
```

This is equivalent: `[time].[month].currentMember.member_Caption`. If the reason for the `case` is to expand `feb` to `feburary` then your statement looks ok - I would use `NULL` instead of the string None and also you need to get rid of the gap for `CurrentMember`:

```
CASE 
   WHEN ([time].[month].currentmember IS [time].[month].&[januaray]) THEN 'januaray'
   WHEN ([time].[month].currentmember IS [time].[month].&[feb]) THEN 'feburary'    
        when [time].[month].&[feb] then 'feburary'
ELSE NULL END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more with syntax with my example